# unable to output jar files with gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jar

I have a single project, which has multiple main class files,
I can compile and run the project within my IDE(intelij) however unable to figure out how to output the artifact jars with gradle
here is what I tried:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:1.6.2'
    }
}


group 'polisotinserter'
version '1.0.0'

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.lyoko.pw:443/libs-release-local'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.github.axet', name: 'lookup', version: '0.1.30'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '3.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-ie-driver', version: '3.0.1'
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'

    compile(group: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', name: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', version: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator')
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'


    compile(group: 'AbstractConnectionApi', name: 'AbstractConnectionApi', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'sjxlsx-custom', name: 'sjxlsx-custom', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')

}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://artifactory.lyoko.pw:443/libs-release-local'
            credentials {
                username = "vasilevich"
                password = "APkgGZjFzEM6Kp1yj1Be3fyrKW"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
        compile(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')
    }
}


project(':CGFetcher') {
    dependencies {
        compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
        compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    }
    task assembleRelease(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'release'
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': "CGFetcher",
                    'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                    'Main-Class': 'gui.CGGuiMain'
        }
        baseName = "CGFetcher"
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
    }
    artifacts {
        archives assembleRelease
    }
}
```

after I run this using

```
gradle build
```

I get one jar in the build/libs folder which is called polisotinserter-1.0.0.jar
this is unexcpected, moreover that jar does not contain the manifest I've set in the project() directive.

after a few tests it seems like the project() directive does not run at all so I am quite confused where to go from here? how can I ask gradle to run the

```
project(':CGFetcher') {
```

directive?
thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is, it is not supposed to appear in the projects root, I noticed that when I run gradle build, it also makes a subfolder CGFetcher
this in turn had its own build folder and the relevant jar.
moreover I noticed that it does not use the source of the root project so I had to do this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:1.6.2'
    }
}


group 'polisotinserter'
version '1.0.0'

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.lyoko.pw:443/libs-release-local'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.github.axet', name: 'lookup', version: '0.1.30'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '3.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-ie-driver', version: '3.0.1'
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'

    compile(group: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', name: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', version: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator')
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'


    compile(group: 'AbstractConnectionApi', name: 'AbstractConnectionApi', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'sjxlsx-custom', name: 'sjxlsx-custom', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
    compile(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')

}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/java").getAbsolutePath()
        }
        resources {
            srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/resources").getAbsolutePath()
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://artifactory.lyoko.pw:443/libs-release-local'
            credentials {
                username = "vasilevich"
                password = "APkgGZjFzEM6Kp1yj1Be3fyrKW"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/java").getAbsolutePath()
            }
            resources {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/resources").getAbsolutePath()
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.github.axet', name: 'lookup', version: '0.1.30'

        compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
        compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'

        compile(group: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', name: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', version: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator')
        compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
        compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'


        compile(group: 'AbstractConnectionApi', name: 'AbstractConnectionApi', version: '1.0.0')
        compile(group: 'sjxlsx-custom', name: 'sjxlsx-custom', version: '1.0.0')
        compile(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
        compile(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')


    }
}

project(':CGFetcher') {

    task assembleRelease(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'release'
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': "CGFetcher",
                    'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                    'Main-Class': 'gui.CGGuiMain'
        }
        baseName = "CGFetcher"
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
    }
    artifacts {
        archives assembleRelease
    }
}
```

notice:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/java").getAbsolutePath()
            }
            resources {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/resources").getAbsolutePath()
            }
        }
    }
```

this tells the project to use the root source code.
however a new problem now arose,
I don't know how to make different dependencies per different project it seems that gradle forces me to use ALL the dependencies even if they are not acctualy used in the code, just because the classes are included.
EDIT:
Ok I figured that one too
simpley, give all your subprojects compileOnly(provided in older gradle versions)
and in the actual projects add "compile" here is an example:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://artifactory.lyoko.pw:443/libs-release-local'
            credentials {
                username = "vasilevich"
                password = "APkgGZjFzEM6Kp1yj1Be3fyrKW"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/java").getAbsolutePath()
            }
            resources {
                srcDir new File(rootProject.projectDir, "src/main/resources").getAbsolutePath()
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compileOnly group: 'com.github.axet', name: 'lookup', version: '0.1.30'
        compileOnly group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '3.0.1'
        compileOnly group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-ie-driver', version: '3.0.1'
        compileOnly group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
        compileOnly(group: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', name: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator', version: 'EnglishToHebrewTranslicirator')
        compileOnly group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
        compileOnly(group: 'AbstractConnectionApi', name: 'AbstractConnectionApi', version: '1.0.0')
        compileOnly(group: 'sjxlsx-custom', name: 'sjxlsx-custom', version: '1.0.0')
        compileOnly "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
        compileOnly(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
        compileOnly(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')
        compileOnly group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'

    }
}

project(':CGFetcher') {
    dependencies {
        compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3"
        compile(group: 'programupdater', name: 'Programs-Updater', version: '1.0.0')
        compile(group: 'com.intellij', name: 'forms_rt', version: '7.0.3+')
        compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'

    }
    task assembleRelease(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'release'
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': "CGFetcher",
                    'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                    'Main-Class': 'gui.CGGuiMain'
        }
        baseName = "CGFetcher"
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
    }
    artifacts {
        archives assembleRelease
    }
}
```

this results in no errors and the resulting jar is as small as its supposed to be.